# TranslateTransition wont work second time

Tags: javafx-2, translate-animation

```
public void sky(Node node, double xDest, double yDest) {

    TranslateTransition tTrans = new TranslateTransition(
            Duration.seconds(4), node);

    // tTrans.setFromX(xPlec);
    tTrans.setToX(xDest);
    tTrans.setRate(2);
    tTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

    // tTrans.setFromY(yPlec);
    tTrans.setToY(yDest);
    tTrans.setRate(2);
    tTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

    node.setLayoutX(node.getLayoutX() + xDest);
    node.setLayoutY(node.getLayoutY() + yDest);

    tTrans.play();



}
```

And here is my method for when the button is pressed

```
public void setDateFwd(MouseEvent event) {



    bFwd.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {



        if (data.getValue().equals(LocalDate.of(2014, 8, 15))) {



            sky(Sirius, 35.5, 4.5);
            sky(Procyon, 35.5, 4.5);
            sky(Beetlegeuse, 35.5, 4.5);
            sky(Polux, 35.5, 4.5);
            sky(Capella, 35.5, 4.5);
            sky(Regulus, 35.5, 4.5);
            sky(Rigel, 35.5, 4.5);
            sky(Aldebaran, 35.5, 4.5);
            sky(Castor, 35.5, 4.5);
            sky(Mirphak, 35.5, 4.5);



        }

    });

}
```

if i click it the first time it works fine(it moves my object from point A to point B using animation) but if i click it the second time it just relocates the object(it makes it dissapear from point A and appear in point B) and i want it to move it from point A to point B so i can see it move along the distance, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `fromXProperty` and `fromYProperty` properties and should not change the layout values

```
public void sky(Node node, double xDest, double yDest) {

    TranslateTransition tTrans = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(4), node);

    tTrans.setFromX(0);
    tTrans.setFromY(0);

    tTrans.setToX(xDest);
    tTrans.setToY(yDest);

    tTrans.setRate(2);
    tTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

    tTrans.play();
}
```

Comment: @MarcIonutStegarescu you can use by tTrans.setFromX(0); and tTrans.setFromY(0);

Comment: thank you it works just fine but it needs this so it doesnt start from beginning  node.setLayoutX(node.getLayoutX() + xDest);
   node.setLayoutY(node.getLayoutY() + yDest);